how to reach out button inside lightnig-layout-item
We have some markup like
 <lightning-layout-item size="1" class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-top_x-large" 
                onclick={handlePerformClick}>
                <template lwc:if={isSpecialCase}>
                    <lightning-button label={START_CAPTION}
                        class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" 
                        disabled={serviceDisabled}>
                    </lightning-button>
                </template>

and handlePerformClick looks like
 async handlePerformClick(e) {
    try {
        console.log('target:', e.target);
        const trgt = e.target.querySelector('button');
        console.log('target:', trgt);

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }

but everytime trgt stands for null for some reasons. Of course, e.target is ightning-layout-item as expected. What's wrong?
Of course i'm clicking on lightnig-button inside

In your component (in its DOM) there is no button element inside lightning-layout-item, only lightning-button, so that's the only one you can find via querySelector. The lightning-button adds a button to its own DOM, but you cannot reach it due to Shadow DOM. Anyway this seems an XY Problem, why would you like to target that button element?
